# GitHub Atom - Remove the center line in the editor

Tags: github, atom-editor

I just downloaded the GitHub Atom Editor and I'm customizing it.

But I couldn't remove the line that is the middle of the editor.

[image: Line in the middle of the screen.]

Anyone help me out how to remove that line?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

This line is provided by the wrap-guide package. You have the following options to remove the line:

## Option 1

Disable the *wrap-guide* package. Go to *Atom > Preferences > Packages*, type "wrap" into the search box, then wait for the *wrap-guide* package to show up under *Core Packages*, and click the *Disable* button there.

## Option 2

Or add the following to your user stylesheet. Use *Atom > Open Your Stylesheet* to open the `styles.less` file in the editor, then add the following:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .wrap-guide {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Once you save the file, the line will be gone.

More info can be found here: https://discuss.atom.io/t/vertical-line-in-editor/2717

**Update 2015-06-28** Updated selector due to updates in the Atom style classes. The above now works in Atom 1.0+.

Comment: Didn't work - @byroncorrales answer worked. Upvoting that.

Comment: Why do I need this line ?

Comment: I think this should be disabled by default imho.

Comment: Just go to File > Settings > Packages > search for: wrap > Wrap Guide > click Disable. That's all

Comment: Note: Atom gives you a 'deprecation cop' error when you do this, and suggests that you replace -> 'atom-text-editor::shadow { .wrap-guide {...}}' with -> atom-text-editor.editor .wrap-guide {...}

Answer (score 23):

Disable the `wrap-guide` package.

Using settings-view: open by entering <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> enter "wrap guide" in *Filter packages* input, click the package name in the sidebar, and click *Disable* in the main window.  Or using your *config.cson* file: add "wrap-guide" in your your `disabledPackages` array.

You can't uninstall it because it is a core package (relased by Atom).

However, you can change where it shows up by changing your `preferredLineLength`.  Using settings view, click *Settings*, find the "Preferred Line Length" input and enter an integer.  In addition, this setting can be changed per syntax by each languages' settings (Find the language in the side bar and adjust the "Preferred Line Length
" input).

Answer (score 11):

In Atom v1.18.0:

Menu - > Packages -> Settings View -> Manage Packages
Scroll to the bottom and click "Disable" on wrap-guide package

Screenshot - Manage Packages:

[image: Screenshot - Manage Packages]

Screenshot - wrap-guide:

[image: Screenshot - wrap-guide]

Answer (score 6):

You need to go to "Settings" and then click on the button "Open Config Folder".

Add to the file style.less

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .wrap-guide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable that line in the latest version, go to:

`file > settings > packages > in the search box type: wrap`

The core package: `wrap guide` should appear, click `disable`.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new syntax available (listed in the atom only), that is :

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .wrap-guide {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

otherwise, it will automatically upgrade, to prevent the breakage with existing style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

This line starts to show up once after the latest update.  There are many ways to remove a vertical line in Atom Editor

**First Way:**

Disable the `wrap-guide` package. Go to Atom > File > Setting > Packages, Search "*wrap-guide*" package and  *Disable* there.

**Second Way:**

if you want to disable, not need to uninstall. You could also use this in your stylesheet:

Go to File > Stylesheet. 
Now the **style.less** a file will be opened. You have to type the following code to disable the vertical line and don't forget to save file.

```
.editor {
  .wrap-guide {
    visibility: hidden!important;
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
.editor {
    .wrap-guide {
        opacity: .05; //barely visible
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the horizontal line, go to Settings => Packages, find and disable a "wrap-guide". Then go to Settings = > Editor, choose a "Soft Wrap".

Enjoy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question was already answered in that exact same way, including pictures. When you answer a question, try to expand on an existing answer (as a suggested edit to the existing answer) or provide an alternative way to do it; otherwise your post is just taking up space.