# How to remove this line marked in white in atom?

Tags: atom-editor

[Zoom to see the line please :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ0C8.png)

As now we cannot see the line in picture
But if you zoom you will see a line in marked area

Help me to solve please
As sometimes it irritates

Comment: This line shows the maximum length for the rows you type. You can remove it by disabling [wrap-guide](https://discuss.atom.io/t/line-in-the-middle-of-editor/41999) in settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579775/github-atom-remove-the-center-line-in-the-editor/25582335#25582335